# Calculate number of days to reach top of staircase

Tags: problem-solving

based on given input I want to calculate the number of days required to reach the top of the staircase.

There are total **N** of stairs. He climbs **X** stairs upwards in a day and he came downstairs in the night by **Y** stairs.

As I am an absolute beginner in math. I don't where to start. Basically I want to form an equation to solve this problem.

```
n = 100;
x= 5
y =1
```

Comment: Where does the frog end up at the end of the first day? How about the second day? By the way, this is a variant of the famous [frog and well problem](http://www.crazyforcode.com/frog-puzzle/).

Answer (score 0):

Calculate his height at the end of each day:-

Day 1  $X$

Day 2  $2X-Y$

Day 3  $3X-2Y$

Can you now see a formula for his height at the end of Day $D$?

Equate your result to $N$ and you have the equation you want.